# add site/index.php/city as a codeigniter url routing not working

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, url, url-routing

I have writing codeigniter URL routes for my site, the route is

```
$route['index.php/([a-zA-Z0-9---_%])+'] = 'site/index/$1';
```

when i try to access the link like as below

```
http://localhost/site/index.php/india
```

is not working, it redirects to 404 page.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a link

```
http://localhost/site/index.php/india
```

You need write this route:

```
$route['site/index.php/(:any)'] = 'site/index/$1';
```